# HTML5 validation not working On OnChange select box form Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

HTML5 validation not working On OnChange select box form Submit .

If i have use submit button validation work ,
but i need `onChange` form submit and html% validation

```
<form action="do.php" method="post">
    <select id="myselect" name="myselect" onchange="this.form.submit()" required="">
        <option value="">
            select
        </option>

        <option value="1">
            One
        </option>

        <option value="2">
            Two
        </option>

        <option value="3">
            Three
        </option>

        <option value="4">
            Four
        </option>
    </select> <select id="myselect2" name="myselect2" onchange="this.form.submit()" required="">
        <option value="">
            select
        </option>

        <option value="5">
            five
        </option>

        <option value="6">
            six
        </option>

        <option value="7">
            seven
        </option>
    </select>
</form>
```

this was condition On change form submit with out validate other select box .
please help .

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 validation applies only when the form is submitted using HTML constructs. If it is submitted with a script, no HTML5 validation takes place. Thus, you need to code your own validation in JavaScript.

Reference: HTML5 LC, 4.10.22.3 [Form submission algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#form-submission-algorithm), where item 4 list the conditions for performing validation, including the requirement that the “submitted from `submit()` method flag” is not set.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this 'hack' http://jsfiddle.net/MGhA7/.

You specify `<select required="required">` so value can not be empty, and then add `<option value="" selected disabled>empty</option>` so default value is empty and can not be selected again.

EDIT: a little more explanation.

This way, form can not be submitted because "selected" value is actually "" (empty), which is not allowed by "required" attribute; and when user changes selection, the default value can not be selected again because of "disabled" attribute.